# Are there performance implication when using one-to-many bi-directional relationships in Entity Framework?

Tags: linq, entity-framework

We have been implementing our ERD in EF.

[image]

Code First for Project

```cs
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_ProjectGUID", IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public Guid GUID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256), Index("IX_ProjectName", IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserAttribute> UserAttributes { get; set; }
}
```

Code First for UserAttributes

```cs
public class UserAttribute
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserAttributeID { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Project_Atttribute_Name", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectID")]
    public virtual Project Project{ get; set; }

    [Index("IX_Project_Atttribute_Name", 2, IsUnique = true)]
    public int AttributeTypeID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AttributeTypeID")]
    public virtual SystemUserAttribute SystemUserAttribute { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(256), Index("IX_Project_Atttribute_Name", 3, IsUnique = true)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserBooleanAttribute> UserBooleanAttributes { get; set; }

}
```

So you can see from the last line of each of those classes a 1-many bidirectional relationship is setup.

Before I introduced this 1-many collection I would of been required to todo:

```
        var jar = context.Projects
            .Where(p=>p.ProjectID==1)
            .Join(
                context.UserAttributes,
                a => a.ProjectID, b => b.ProjectID,
                (a, b) => new {a, b});
```

Now I only have to do:

```
Projects.Where(prj=>prj.ProjectID==1).Select(ua=>ua.UserAttributes).Single()
```

Since Lazy-Loading in effect, is there really no degradation to performance?

*Single -- Why do I need to call this or something similar like FirstOrDefault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks ok.  A few quirks to it, like why you are assigning both an ID and GUID to a project.  Really should be one or the other.

Single seems out of place because you are selecting the UserAttributes, which could be one or more of them.  Single implies there is only one, and if that was true, your design is more complex than it should be.

I assume you'll be adding navigation properties for string and integer as well, which is just fine.

The `User*Attributes` classes should also have navigation properties to UserAttributes as well.

I've tried analyzing your design, and all I can say is it gives me a headache.  I'm going to assume there is some outside reason you've chosen the PK's you have instead of using natural keys.  From a glance, UserAttributes seems poorly named.  It's not user attributes, it appears to be a project's attributes (or attributes that are assignable to a user for each project).  I would also ask if breaking your attributes up into 3 separate tables instead of always serialzing the value into a string is worth the headaches, because it's not likely to save you any space (with the exception of integer -- perhaps) and greatly slow down every query you need to make.

Comment: We have to download / upload individual projects, hence the guid.

Comment: Good point about the UserAttributes really being UserProjectAttributes.  We are using multiple tables as the type specifies what sort of queries can be made off of it.  For example, UserStringsAttribute can allow a Contains search, where a UserBooleanAttribute cannot.

Comment: As for why we don't want to use composite pks, performance is the issue.